# if statement for input (cin)

Tags: c++

Practicing some C++, I ran into some code from a book.
The usage of the if statement with the break seams a bit unecessary to me:

if (!(cin >> dstep)) 
break;

This seams a bit hackish to me and simply using a cin >> dstep with no if or break runs the program fine.  Any thoughts?

```
                    int main()
                {
                    using namespace VECTOR;

                    srand(time(0));     //seed random-number generator
                    double direction;
                    Vector step;        //creates default object
                    Vector result(0.0, 0.0);    //
                    unsigned long steps = 0;
                    double target;
                    double dstep;

                    cout << "Enter target distance (q to quit): ";

                    while (cin >> target)
                    {
                        cout << "Enter step length: ";
                        if (!(cin >> dstep))    //if NOT inputing into dstep THEN break/means if INPUTING is TRUE, keep going and don't break out of loop
                            break; 
                      //cin >> dstep  // why not just use this?
                        while (result.magval() < target)
                        {
                            direction = rand() % 360;
                            step.set(dstep, direction, 'p'); //sets the values dstep and direction based on the form; in this case 'p'
                            result = result + step;
                            steps++;
                        }
                        cout << "After " << steps << " steps, the subject "
                            "has the following location:\n";
                        cout << result << endl;
                        result.polar_mode();
                        cout << " or\n" << result << endl;
                        cout << "Average outward distance per step = "
                            << result.magval() / steps << endl;
                        steps = 0;
                        result.set(0.0, 0.0);
                        cout << "Enter target distance (q to quit): ";
                    }
                    cout << "Bye!\n";

                    cin.get();
                    return 0;
                }
```

Comment: without `break` what happens when you enter invalid length (may be a string) for the `"Enter step length" prompt?

Comment: Entering a char such at 'Q' or 'P' or anything not ant int will exit the main loop and print "bye"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to either enable exceptions or check every stream input operation, otherwise you risk getting into an infinite loop, or just getting wrong results, when the input is malformed.

Comment: Thanks for the tips; yea right now I am just wanting to know syntax-wise if I can eliminate the if break and just use the simple cin >> dstep.  The book appears to be using the if for input validation "if not" then so and so..